# How do i display my list as a string in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

Here is the code i have used to build the list.

```
type Title = String
type Actor = [String]
type Year = Int
type Fans = [String]
type Film = (Title, Actor, Year, Fans)

type Database = [Film]  
filmDatabase :: Database
filmDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"])...]
```

below is the code i Am using to try and display the list as the string.

```
titleAsString :: Title -> String
titleAsString = show

actorsAsString :: Actor -> String
actorsAsString = intercalate ", " . map show

yearAsString :: Year -> String
yearAsString = show

fansAsString :: Fans -> String
fansAsString = intercalate ", " . map show

filmsAsString :: [Film] -> String
filmsAsString (t, a, y, f) = unlines [titleAsString t, actorsAsString a, yearAsString y, fansAsString f]

filmsAsStringDB = unlines . map filmsAsString
```

here is the error message i get..

```
 Couldn't match type ‘(Title, Actor, Year, Fans)’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Title
      Actual type: [Film]
    In the first argument of ‘titleAsString’, namely ‘t’
    In the expression: titleAsString t
```

I think the problem is i haven't converted them all to a string but i'm not sure how to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `filmsAsString` to be of type `[Film] -> String`, yet its argument is clearly just a `Film`.

Comment: Oh yes i see my mistake thank you! Types in haskell confuse me as i am very new to it!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead

```
filmAsString :: Film -> String
filmAsString (t, a, y, f) = unlines [titleAsString t, actorsAsString a, yearAsString y, fansAsString f]

databaseAsString :: Database -> String
databaseAsString = unlines . map filmAsString
```